# How to handle "Unhandled Exception" without using "throws XXXException"

Tags: java, exception

I have a task where I need to handle "Unhandled Exception" without using "throws XXXException". Here is the situation:

I need to retry a method if it throws JMSException.

```
public void retry(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException, JMSException {
    restartConnection(); //
}
```

```
public void restartConnection() throws JMSException {
    init(); //this is where JMSException is thrown
}
```

and on my send method, I call retry().

```
public void send(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException {
    //exit method if retried enough times.
    if(retryCount > someNumber)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    try {
        producer.send();
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
        retry(retryCount); // this is where Unhandled Exception is.
    }
}
```

What I want to do is when retry() is called from send(), and if restartConnection() is failed and threw JMSException, I want retry() to call send(retryCount++). I don't want to add JMSException on send() method, but it says I need to implement it. Is there way to handle the exception so I don't have JMSException on send()?

Comment: When you reach for ex 10 times the error, how do you want to handle it, logging, print ? this is the way to stop the exception propagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the method with `retryCount+1` but when you reach, for example 10, raise the exception to avoid infinite error

Handle it in `send`

```
public void send(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException {
    //exit method if retried enough times.
    if(retryCount > someNumber)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    try {
        producer.send();
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
        try {
            retry(retryCount); // this is where Unhandled Exception is
        }catch (JMSException ex) {
            if(retryCount < 10)
                send(retryCount+1);
            else
                logger.error(e); // or print or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

---

Handle it in `retry`:

```
public void retry(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException{
    try{
        restartConnection(); //
    }catch (JMSException e) {
        if(retryCount < 10)
            retry(retryCount+1);
        else
            logger.error(e); // or print or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: First solution will resolve the issue, but I am curious if that is regular thing to do. I am pretty new to using try/catch block for exceptions..

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to handle this, but I am not sure this is normal thing to do. Here is what I did:

```
public void send(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException {
    //exit method if retried enough times.
    if(retryCount > someNumber)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    try {
        producer.send();
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
        try {
            retry(retryCount); // this is where Unhandled Exception is
        }
        catch (JMSException ex) {
            send(++retryCount);
        }
    }
}
```

So I am basically using another try/catch block inside of my catch block. This does remove the error, and it works fine, but I am not sure this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like keeping the retry logic contained in the `retry` method is desirable.  This assumes the initial `retryCount` parameter to `send` is a "maximum number of retries to attempt".

```
public void retry(int retryCount) throws MessageGatewayException {

    while (retryCount-- > 0 && !restartConnection());

}
```

And add Boolean result to `restartConnection`:

```
public boolean restartConnection() {
    try {
        init(); 
        return true;
    } catch (JMSException e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Your `send` method is unchanged in this example.